# Editing C# property value from SQL Server when multiple rows provide answer in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Assume I have a SQL table thus:
[Sample Data]

ID1 --------| ID2   | EditColumn        | EditValue
T1017TF | 142   | EyeColor                     |   1
T1017TF | 142   | EyeColor                   |   2
T1017TF | 142   | HairColor                  |   F
T1017TF | 142   | WeightClass          |   A1
T1017TF | 142   | WeightClass          |   A2
T1017TF | 142   | AcceptablePulse   |   1
T1017TF | 142   | AcceptablePulse   |   3

From C# assuming I have the EditValue of each EditColumn in a .Net Class Property corresponding to combined keys ID1 AND ID2.  So, for Key T1017TF/142, the WeightClass= 'A1'or 'A2' would pass validation, but A3 would not.  For a given key combo (T1017TF/142), I must edit for each EditColumn.

What is the best manner in C# or Tranact SQL (up to 2016) to edit repeatedly for each EditColumn? I must be overthinking this..

Thank you ahead of time

Comment: Why would A3 "not pass"? What about F? 3?

Comment: Let me explain further.  I have a "person" (T1017TF/142) - - he has many attributes (EyeColor, HairColor, WeightClass, AcceptablePulse.  The "record" I am editting is retrieved from a CSV.  Those elements (eye, hair, weight) are in separate columns, which I assign to class properties.  In my "editing table" depicted above, A3 is not a valid WeightClass.